# Laravel 5.4 Token mismatch exception VerifyCsrfToken on production

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.4, csrf-protection

I just moved my working `Laravel 5.4` application to production server. On form submission I get

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

I understand the reason of this exception and I can confirm that the token generated within a form and the one in the request headers do match. But the issue still persists.

Any pointers to the actual problem and solution are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you dump out the $_POST values the script is receiving and make sure the token is there, and confirm if the other values from the form are coming through or not?

Comment: @alistairshaw, yes they are there.

Comment: ok so compare the value of the posted csrf token with the value of what's stored in the session by dumping out the session. That's the only comparison that Laravel does before throwing that exception, so they must be somehow different?

Comment: @alistairshaw, I checked they are different. For dumping sessions in controller method `dd($request->session()->all()` doesn't work on production. And still throws the same exception.

So, I checked `storage/frameworks/sessions` folder for latest file updated and the tokens are different

Comment: @alistairshaw, I tried `artisan cache:config` which you know clears and re-caches the configuration. And it worked. 

The reason I think of it is, As I updated some `config/app.php` particularly `APP_URL` env. And laravel was using already cached configuration. Doing this fixed the issue.

What are your thoughts about the reason for this error ?

Comment: Great, I'm super glad you got it sorted! In answer to why in the first place, it sounds as though you copied not only the application but also the cache/session files when you deployed your site to production. Basically everything in the `storage` folder should be ignored on deploy.